# Thread local storage GCC Compiler

Tags: multithreading, gcc, ubuntu

I declare a variable `__thread int my_id`;
Info of my platform and compiler:

```
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)
```

I use flag -lpthread to compile.
But Compiler complains: `error: storage class specified for 'my_id'`.

Comment: and you have tried what?

Comment: Please show the original declaration in the header file along with its listing in the source code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've declared thread local storage for a variable. This kind of storage for a variable cannot be declared as existing on the stack. Making it part of a struct/class implicitly permits it to be on the stack.

The only effective way to accomplish this is to make the variable `static` - the reason for this is that it causes the variable to be stored in the thread local storage pool instead of on the stack.

e.g. at the global scope:

```
__thread int my_id;
```

will work, as the variable is not in a structure. It can automatically be placed into the thread local storage pool.

for a structure, the following:

```
struct xx {
    __thread int my_id;
};
```

will not work, as the variable can end up on the stack, so you need to use:

```
struct xx {
    static __thread int my_id;
};
```

which causes it to be placed in the thread local storage pool, and thus be a valid thread variable.

*Note*: I'd previously described the variable as being on the heap. This is strictly speaking incorrect - the variable is taken from a per-thread block of memory that is allocated at thread creation time; I've renamed the term to the 'thread local storage' pool. This pool is of a platform specific size, and can be filled up if you have too many separate `__thread` variables.

The [Wikipedia entry on Thread Local Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) explains this in good detail (including some gotchas).

Comment: Just a nit: Not exactly heap storage. It's global storage which is fixed in size and loaded and initialized as part of the executable or library. Heap storage is dynamic.

Comment: True; I'll try to tidy up the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable static.